# Printing Object in multiple parts

Tags: 3d-design, abs

Is there any software/methods to automatically splice objects into multiple pieces sort of like a jig saw puzzle so that I can combine them together and bypass the build plate size limit?

As an example I have this 2D image that I want to print out but my printers size limit is roughly the size of the blue "squares." It's pretty tedious and time consuming to do this manually. Also, any tips on getting seamless lines or proper alignment when gluing these pieces together are appreciated.
[image]

Comment: AFAIK most of 3d apps have repeat (tiling) operation (also called pattern) so you can create one tile and repeat it in grid, and they also have boolean operation which helps to slice on object by another. please notice you gotta do it only for borders of your main obj. as all insied tiles are the same (full black). please write what kind of app you use so we could leade you precisely in this app. you can also do slicing in any 2d (yes - 2d) app. slice your bitmap into smaller parts and extrude them into 3d objs.

Comment: I've taken out the texture for simplicity but it'll be there. I've used Inkscape to create the bitmap but I'm creating my 3D model in Fusion 360 and printing in Repetier. To note in my picture is the top right of the car hood getting cut into a super tiny piece not falling into any of the blocks. I'd ideally use some method to make the parts all roughly the same size.

Comment: while on model: create > pattern or while on sketch: sketch > rectangular pattern. EDIT: for cutting object/skatch please take a look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5o7-4lSjyQw

Comment: If you're really dealing with an output that many times the size of the build plate, I recommend trying to adjust the cut lines so there's a bunch of plain-solid-squares surrounded by chunks with shape to them.

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, you're trying to partition your object into smaller pieces with the hopes of putting them back together in a manner similar to a Jigsaw puzzle.

There are two options that I know of to do this, which requires using OpenSCAD:

- The [PuzzleCut](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:35834) library - This allows you to disassemble your object into a multiple pieces that can be assembled together in a jigsaw puzzle type manner
- The [PinCut](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:310652) library - This allows you to disassemble your objects into multiple pieces that than be reassembled using the pins and corresponding holes on the pieces.

Answer (score 1):

- You mentioned youre using Fusion 360; if so, you could just [split your final body](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/fusion-360/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/how-to-split-solid-two-bodies.html) or component into separate bodies.  Then you could export each body separately.
- Slic3r and Slic3r PE both have the **Cut** command, but unfortunately it only will cut on the XY plane.
- If you are on Windows 10, 3D Builder has a good tool for splitting STL files.

  - Open your STL in 3D Builder
  - Use the **Edit** > **Split** command
  - Adjust the plane to where you want the object cut
  - Select **Keep both** and click **✓ Split**
  - Note that you can't export individual objects; you must copy each object into a new 3D Builder window to save it separately.
- Meshmixer is an excellent tool to learn overall but has a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to put it that way, but does 3D printing the best "tool" for your case?

it seems you want to generate a huge flat file when a CnC would be the best to generate a clean and solid part.

Otherwise, as others suggets you are looking for a tooling tool.